# Seapine Surround SCM ticket creation

Tags: ticket-system, surroundscm, testtrack

I'm relatively new with Seapines SurroundSCM API, so I might just be missing something obvious. Is there a way to generate a ticket that is then sent to TestTrack whenever a file is  checked in using the SurroundSCM API? I'm being told there is a way to do it, but I can't find anything in the documentation or their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to perform this action from the Surround SCM API because creating a defect/ticket is a TestTrack operation. Here are two potential approaches to take.

(1) Your application can use the addDefect function in the TestTrack API to create a new defect/ticket. So your application would use the Surround SCM API to check in the file and the TestTrack API to create the defect/ticket.

(2) You could create a second application to create a new defect/ticket via the TestTrack API. This second application could be run as the result of a Surround SCM trigger event. You could configure the preconditions of the SCM trigger to be limited to a specific group of users or specific repository.

Comment: Thanks :) I knew this was the issue, but I needed backup on this. I kept being told it was possible to do even though everything on the site points to it not being possible!